# Get the stacktrace of all the classes executed

Tags: java, jvm, cucumber, stack-trace, regression-testing

I am creating a map where when an acceptance/regression test case is run, It should give me all the Class instances it is called So that I can map these classes with their respective regression test case. Is there any way that I can get all the class instances it is executed from java when a test case is run?

Ex: regression test case A -> service class(which contains all the dependencies class)

Comment: You can use the get stack trace method from Throwable https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getStackTrace()

Comment: [`Thread.getAllStackTraces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getAllStackTraces())